# Can i get more info out of this strict mode LeakedClosableViolation message?

Tags: android, android-strictmode

I just saw a pretty weird message in the logs of my Android app:

> W/System: A resource failed to call close.

So, i turned on Strict mode's "detectLeakedClosableObjects", but i got a stack trace that i can't really make heads or tails of, since it doesn't include anthing about my app. See below.

I was wondering if there's any way i can get any more information as to why this is happening? Is it perhaps outside my app somehow? Pointers appreciated:

> D/StrictMode: StrictMode policy violation: android.os.strictmode.LeakedClosableViolation: A resource was acquired at attached stack trace but never released. See java.io.Closeable for information on avoiding resource leaks. Callsite: close
> at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidCloseGuardReporter.report(StrictMode.java:1992)
> at dalvik.system.CloseGuard.warnIfOpen(CloseGuard.java:347)
> at sun.nio.fs.UnixSecureDirectoryStream.finalize(UnixSecureDirectoryStream.java:580)
> at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.doFinalize(Daemons.java:291)
> at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.runInternal(Daemons.java:278)
> at java.lang.Daemons$Daemon.run(Daemons.java:139)
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:920)

Comment: I got the same trace even when reducing my app to nothing. I guess the problem isn't our code.

Comment: allright, thanks for responding